# Determinant vanishing over polynomial ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, determinant

Let $R=\mathbb C[t_1,\ldots,t_N]$ be a polynomial ring in some number of variables. Assume that $f_{ij}\in R$ are homogeneous linear polynomials for $1\le i,j\le n$. If $\det(f_{ij})=0$, I can consider this equation over $K:=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and get $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in K$, not all zero, with the property that 
$$ \forall i:\quad \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot f_{ij} = 0 $$
Now, I can clear denominators and assume $\lambda_j\in R$. Since the $f_{ij}$ are homogeneous, I can also assume that the $\lambda_j$ are homogeneous. In a similar way, I can find homogeneous $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n\in R$ which are not all zero with
$$ \forall j:\quad \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i\cdot f_{ij} = 0$$

**Question:** Under what conditions can I choose either all the $\lambda_j$ *or* all the $\mu_i$ to be constant? Is this always the case?

Comment: The answer seems to be "not always", but for fairly trivial reasons. Maybe I am misunderstanding. What if $f_{1,1}=f_{2,2}=x$ and $f_{1,2}=f_{2,1}=y$, then $\det(f_{i,j})=xy-yx=0$, yet there are no constants $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 y=0$. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @AlexYoucis $\det(f_{ij})=x^2-y^2\ne0$.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Oops, indexing mistake :) What I mean is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x & y\\ x & y\end{pmatrix}$ or its transpose $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$. This does have zero determinant, but the entries of the second, and rows of the first don't have relations with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe I'm still misunderstanding?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: You are very right, although this does not seem satisfying to me. Let me make an edit =).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain This sounds like it's going to really have nothing more sophisticated than doing linear algebra on the $N$-dimensional space of homogenous linear polynomials.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: What do you mean? Do you think the answer is affirmative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of good answers in my repost at Mathoverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143250/on-matrices-in-linear-forms-with-vanishing-determinant

In particular, there is a counterexample for $n=3$.